# How to checkout a repository using Mercurial (hg) in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, download, mercurial

I am trying to download a sample project of CorePlot from:

```
http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/checkout
```

There, they have mentioned below command to execute for getting a legal copy:

```
hg clone https://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/ core-plot
```

But My Mac OS X terminal says that there is no command called `hg`.

What should I do?

Comment: See the link on this page of that site under GUI and IDE access. That link will lead you to a page with different versions of Mercurial for various operating systems: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/checkout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Download).

Comment: Have you tried installing with `sudo`?

Comment: Run the command `sudo port install mercurial`

Comment: If it can't find the port command, something is wrong with your installation of Macports.

Comment: I have installed fink, Mac ports & Python successfully but I am still not able to execute the command mentioned in question. (hg clone).

Comment: Where is the `port` binary located? Type `which port` and if a path to it isn't displayed, you'll need to add it's location to your path.